# Objective-C Memory Management on Static Variables

Tags: objective-c

```
///**************************
// MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

static MyClass *myClass = NULL;

@implementation MyClass
 (MyClass *)sharedMyClass {
 myClass = NULL;
 myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
 return myClass;
}

@end
```

Hi Experts, I just want to know myClass is a static ObjC object, it will be automatically released by ARC when no one is referencing it anymore, so no memory leak? is it correct?

Comment: You should look at the ```dispatch_once``` pattern. Here note you have a strong pointer to the class in ```static MyClass *myClass``` so unless you set that to ```nil``` it will never be released. But this is not really a leak as, presumably, for this kind of a thing you need some instance of the class ready throughout the life of the app?

Comment: Thanks, skaak. I intend to write this code instead of dispatch_one, I just want to test whether ARC would release the static variable automatically if it's nil. e.g. sharedMyClass will be called multiple times...

Comment: so you said "so unless you set that to nil it will never be released", that means the ARC should release myClass right?

Comment: Hi DT ... yes if you explicitly set it to nil and nothing else has a (strong) hold on it then it will be released. I mention ```dispatch_once``` as it seems you need a singleton. This is quite normal but typically happens a bit differently to how you do it. Now what you do is fine (and common) also, of course, but sometimes you create a single instance of your class and access it e.g. like the default file manager or standard user preferences or the default notification center. I trust you know which classes I am talking about.

Comment: Is a `+` missing? `+ (MyClass *)sharedMyClass`

Comment: ... All of these singletons needed to go a bit further than just a static variable and it is good to be aware of how to do so. I'll post an example just to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a singleton class instance that you can use throughout your app if you need to. It never gets released and is not intended to be released.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ ( MyClass * ) singleton;

@end
```

That is the interface, so you'll access it as `MyClass.singleton` for example. The implementation is like this. The reason for the `dispatch_once` fluff is to make it safe in an environment where it might be accessed from multiple places all at once.

```
@implemenation MyClass ()

+ ( MyClass * ) singleton
{
    static MyClass * a;
    static dispatch_once_t t;
    
    dispatch_once ( & t, ^ {
        
        a = [[MyClass alloc] init];

    } );

    return a;
}

@end
```

Note that this also rely on a static variable. That variable is retained from creation time until forever or the app quits.

Answer (score 0):

`static MyClass *myClass` creates a reference to the pointer stored into that value. As long as `myClass` will hold a valid object address, that object will not be deallocated. Basically this variable adds a +1 to the reference count of the stored object. If you want for that object to have a change to deallocate, you'll have to change the value of this variable to point to something else (or back to `nil`).

As a side note, `static` in Objective-C has no relation to the static modifier of class members, in C/Objective-C `static` means a symbol that is not visible to other files, e.g. a `fileprivate` one from Swift.